# Table already exists in magento

Tags: magento

```
 a:5:{i:0;s:1615:"Error in file: "F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\install-1.6.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'magentocatalog_product_entity' already exists, query was: CREATE TABLE `magentocatalog_product_entity` (
  `entity_id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'Entity ID' ,
  `entity_type_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Entity Type ID' ,
  `attribute_set_id` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Attribute Set ID' ,
  `type_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL default 'simple' COMMENT 'Type ID' ,
  `sku` varchar(64) NULL COMMENT 'SKU' ,
  `has_options` smallint NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Has Options' ,
  `required_options` smallint UNSIGNED NOT NULL default '0' COMMENT 'Required Options' ,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Creation Time' ,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL default NULL COMMENT 'Update Time' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_MAGENTOCATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ENTITY_TYPE_ID` (`entity_type_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_MAGENTOCATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID` (`attribute_set_id`),
  INDEX `IDX_MAGENTOCATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_SKU` (`sku`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_8B7CB20052FE7C64E79769F6B728AF6C` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `magentoeav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_861F86D05C5B679BB47B60BE3D1BDD39` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_type_id`) REFERENCES `magentoeav_entity_type` (`entity_type_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) COMMENT='Catalog Product Table' ENGINE=INNODB charset=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci";i:1;s:958:"#0 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(644): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(421): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.6.0.0.19.1.5')
#2 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(327): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.6.0.0.19.1.5')
#3 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(235): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(428): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:44:"/magento/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/";s:11:"script_name";s:18:"/magento/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: I have installed more than 10 times

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: You should also read [ask].